# Converting SAS code to R code

Tags: r, model

I have been trying to convert a SAS code that calculates Simple Regression and Mixed Models. I've achieved to convert simple Regression but when it comes to Mixed Model, my trials turn into fails. The SAS code shnown below is the code that I try to convert

"parc" "m" "dap" "ht" is the header labes of dataset, respectively.

```
data algoritmo ;
input parc m dap ht ;
lnH = LOG(ht-1.3);
lnD = LOG(dap) ;
cards ;
8   1   24.3    26.7
8   1   29.9    30.7
8   1   32.6    31.7
8   1   35.9    33.7
8   1   36.5    32.5
22  2   22.3    21.0
22  2   26.9    23.1
22  2   26.9    20.5
22  2   32.4    21.5
22  2   33.5    25.0
85  3   33.6    33.5
85  3   36.0    33.0
85  3   37.0    35.0
85  3   40.8    35.0

;
run ;

/* Simpre Regression Model */
PROC REG DATA=algoritmo ;
model lnH = lnD ;
output out=out p=pred ;
run ; quit ;

/* Mixed-Effects Model */
PROC MIXED DATA=algoritmo COVTEST METHOD=REML  ;
TITLE ' lnH = (B0+bok)+(B1+b1k)*lnd ' ;
MODEL lnH = lnD / S OUTPM=outpm OUTP=outp ;
RANDOM intercept lnD /SUBJECT=m s G TYPE=UN ;
RUN ;
```

Here is the part of code that I converted. This part of code works perfect for me.

```
data1= read.table(file.choose(), header=T, sep=",")
attach(data1)
lnH=log(ht-1.3)
lnD =log(dap)
data2 = cbind(data1,lnH, lnD)
#Simple Linear Model
model1 = lm(lnH~lnD,data=data2)
summary(model1)
```

But for the rest I'm stuck.

```
model2 = lme(lnH~lnD ,data=data2,random=~1|lnD / m, method= "REML",  weights=varPower(0.2,form=~dap))
summary(model2)
```

Comment: I don't speak SAS, but I suspect you should use `random=~lnD|m`, i.e., you might want a random intercept and slope grouped by `m`.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your precious tip. I think it worked for me well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the help oh Roland, replacing `random=~1|lnD` with `random=~lnD|m`worked pretty good.